# SQL Server GROUP BY but need one detail column

Tags: sql-server, datetime, group-by, nested

I have a factory labor collection (time) system that is tracking worker's time and the jobs they are working on. In this particular case, I am trying to determine who forgot to swipe in based on the ON/OFF type of each worker's latest swipe in a table of data. Consider three workers, John, Matt, and Sean. Their days all start at 5:30 AM. Here's some play data:

```
create table johnmtest (empl_ID varchar(5), ONOFF varchar(2), TSTAMP DATETIME);
insert into jmtest (empl_ID, ONOFF, TSTAMP) values ('JOHNM', 'ON', '2020-01-15 05:31:06');
insert into jmtest (empl_ID, ONOFF, TSTAMP) values ('SEANW', 'ON', '2020-01-15 05:33:17');
insert into jmtest (empl_ID, ONOFF, TSTAMP) values ('MATTD', 'ON', '2020-01-15 05:35:31');
insert into jmtest (empl_ID, ONOFF, TSTAMP) values ('SEANW', 'OF', '2020-01-15 13:07:41');
insert into jmtest (empl_ID, ONOFF, TSTAMP) values ('JOHNM', 'OF', '2020-01-15 14:15:29');
insert into jmtest (empl_ID, ONOFF, TSTAMP) values ('JOHNM', 'ON', '2020-01-15 14:21:11');
insert into jmtest (empl_ID, ONOFF, TSTAMP) values ('MATTD', 'OF', '2020-01-15 15:01:27');
insert into jmtest (empl_ID, ONOFF, TSTAMP) values ('MATTD', 'ON', '2020-01-15 15:15:48');
```

So, we see that John swiped in on his first workorder at 5:31 AM, Matt started at 5:35, and Sean started at 5:33. These are all 'ON' swipes, the guys are working and the clock is running.

- As the day progresses John finishes (swiped off) his first workorder at 2:15 PM (OF), took a few minutes break, and swiped ON his second workorder at 2:21 PM. He is actively working.
- Same thing with Matt. Matt works on his first workorder from 5:35 AM to 3:01 PM (ON and OF). He takes a short break and starts his second workorder at 3:15 PM. He is also actively working.
- But Sean is the problem. Sean swiped ON his first workorder at 5:33 AM and swiped OF at 1:07 PM. I look out on the factory floor and see Sean working at a drill press, but his very latest swipe in time was an off swipe (OF). That means he is physically working but he is not swiped ON for time recording.

So I'm trying to do a GROUP BY of each employee with their MAX time. That's easy with a

```
select empl_ID, max(TSTAMP) from jmtest GROUP BY empl_ID
```

But I need to get the **ONOFF column** in there somehow so I can see if an employee's very last swipe was an ON or an OF. I'm trying to get to this:

```
empl_ID     ONOFF    TSTAMP
-------     -----    ------
SEANW        OF      2020-01-15 13:07:41
JOHNM        ON      2020-01-15 14:21:11
MATTD        ON      2020-01-15 15:15:48
```

In fact, we intend to port this data out to large TV displays on the factory floor so the supervisors can see who is not swiped ON. In that case, I'm hoping an additional WHERE clause of only the OF rows would whittle the list down further to only this:

```
empl_ID     ONOFF    TSTAMP
-------     -----    ------
SEANW        OF      2020-01-15 13:07:41
```

Then the Supervisors can go find Sean and yell at him. While it sounds easy to just look out on the floor and compare to the data list, there's 400 guys out there. So, just the OF record display would be extremely helpful.

Is it possible to do some kind of grouping that then joins in the ON/OF column for the full picture? Or a two-level query?
Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem, and here's how it's commonly implemented in TSQL:

```
with q as
(
    select *, row_number() over (partition by empl_ID order by TSTAMP desc) rn
    from johnmtest
)
select empl_ID, ONOFF, TSTAMP
from q
where rn = 1
```

outputs

```
empl_ID ONOFF TSTAMP
------- ----- -----------------------
JOHNM   ON    2020-01-15 14:21:11.000
MATTD   ON    2020-01-15 15:15:48.000
SEANW   OF    2020-01-15 13:07:41.000

(3 rows affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by and join. ie:

```
select t.* 
from jmTest t
inner join 
(select empl_Id, max(tStamp) as lastRec from jmTest group by empl_Id) mx
on t.empl_id = mx.empl_id and t.tStamp = mx.lastRec
where t.ONOFF = 'OF';
```

EDIT:
[DbFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=77bd8460508f3c7127a15c61e8c17e90)